# Does the iPod first generation have emojis?

Tags: ipod, emoji

Okay so I asked this before well not exactly but can you get emoji's and the first gen iPod? I have and iPod 4 and an a iPhone 6 and they have emoji's but now I am buying the first and need to know. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference to your other question?

Comment: There isn't really a difference. I guess.